# Get a single entity from a magento model collection

Tags: magento, collections

I'm encountering an issue because I'm sure I'm not doing this correctly with my programming. I have created a custom model in Magento.
In the database table of my model there are several entities with the same attributes...

I need to pick just one from all these entities with the same attribute that I have. For the moment I did this:

```
$myvariable = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection()
->setOrder('idserialkeys', 'asc')
->addFilter('idproduit', 1)
->addFilter('utilise', 0)
->addFilter('customerid', 0)
->addFilter('numcommande', 0)
```

From this loading I have around a hundred results but I need to update only one of these, so just after I'm doing:

```
->setPageSize(1);
```

The problem is that I need a `foreach` after to update my entity

```
foreach($mavaribale as $modifiemoi) {
    // Update of my entity because of course there is only one 
}
```

As you can see I'm obliged to do a loop (for each) even if I have a `setPagesize`... I would like to avoid this loop to optimize my code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you have a collection, and you only need one element, use the `getFirstItem` method. Try this:

```
$modifiemoi = $myvariable->getFirstItem();
```

Make sure that you also use your `setPageSize` call so that you only transfer data for one item.

Comment: what does setPageSize do exactly?

Answer (score 11):

All collections are [`Varien_Data_Collection`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection.html) objects so you can use [`getFirstItem`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Collection.html#getFirstItem):

```
$modifiemoi = $mavaribale->getFirstItem();
```